# Adding views programmatically into tableView cells making scroll jerky and slow

Tags: ios, swift, performance, uitableview, scrollview

Adding views programmatically into tableView cells making scroll jerky and slow. I am adding views programmatically into cell in the delegate function "CellForRowAt". I tried it through delegate function "WillDisplay" but the results are the same.
What is the best possible solution to achieve this?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
       "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
       addViewsInCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath)
       return cell
}

func addViewsInCell(cell: CustomCell, indexPath: IndexPath) {
      //here i am adding some views programmatically
      for i in 0..<3 {
           let customView: CustomView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! customView
           cell.customViewPlacement.addSubview(customView)
      }
}
```

Comment: Could you Please show your code ?

Comment: My crystal ball broke down earlier this week, can you post some code?

Comment: guys, please see the updated question.

Comment: @danishnaeem please add full code. with adding view programmatically.

Comment: yes i did. please see the updated question. 
func addViewsInCell(cell: CustomCell, indexPath: IndexPath) {
      //here i am adding a view by including nib programmatically
      let customView: CustomView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! customView
      cell.customViewPlacement.addSubview(customView)
}

Comment: @danishnaeem you add custom view before check customview already add or not if added then not add else add because cellforrowatindexpath call every time when you scroll tableview so this code add every time custom view that's issue your scroll jerky and slow.

Comment: alright thanks. I will look into it through implementation

Comment: @danishnaeem happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Cell views are reused. Adding a subview every time in `cellForRowAt indexPath:` you end up with multiple copies of the same subview. Instead you should check whether that subview is already added. You could mark your subview with a tag and then use the `viewWithTag` method to test its presence.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add any subviews/custom views inside `tableView: cellForRowAt indexPath:`. This will cause those subviews to be added repeatedly whenever that cell loaded by the table view. Instead create a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and create your subviews inside that subclass if you are working programmatically. Or else if you are working with storyboards, you can create a dynamic prototype cell.

Comment: what if i want to add my customView multiple time one on each other in each row like a table?
for example: 

func addViewsInCell(cell: CustomCell, indexPath: IndexPath) {
      //here i am adding a view by including nib programmatically
      for i in 0..<3 {
                let customView: CustomView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! customView
               cell.customViewPlacement.addSubview(customView)
      }
}